# Get even numbers and odd numbers in order in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

An example:

```
def get_evens_at_back(a_list):
    if not a_list:
      return []
    if a_list[0] % 2 == 1:
      return [a_list[0]] + get_evens_at_back(a_list[1:])
    return get_evens_at_back(a_list[1:])

    print("1.", get_evens_at_back([-1, 2, -3, 4, -2, 3, 5]))
    print("2.", get_evens_at_back([1, 2, -3, 4, 7, 4, -6, 3, -1]))
    print("3.", get_evens_at_back([-4, -2, 6, 8, 6, 2]))
    print("4.", get_evens_at_back([-3, -1, 3, 1, 7, 9]))
    print("5.", get_evens_at_back([]))
```

output:

```
 1. [-1, -3, 3, 5]
 2. [1, -3, 7, 3, -1]
 3. []
 4. [-3, -1, 3, 1, 7, 9]
 5. []
```

I'm trying get a new list with all the odd numbers from the list (in sorted order) at the front and all the even numbers from the list (in sorted order) at the back of the list.  If the list is empty, the function should return an empty list.I'm not sure how to fix it.

expected:

```
 1. [-3, -1, 3, 5, -2, 2, 4]
 2. [-3, -1, 1, 3, 7, -6, 2, 4, 4]
 3. [-4, -2, 2, 6, 6, 8]
 4. [-3, -1, 1, 3, 7, 9]
 5. []
```

Comment: If the first number is even, you just skip over it and recurse on the rest. So you're removing all the even numbers, not moving them to the back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sorted` with a 2-tuple, putting the odd numbers first and then sorting by the magnitude of the numbers for each category:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, -3, 4, 7, 4, -6, 3, -1]
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (x % 2 == 0, x))
[-3, -1, 1, 3, 7, -6, 2, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly readable version, that uses the `filter` built-in function to get all the odd/even values in separate lists, sorts those lists, and then combines them (using the list `+` operator):

```
def is_even(i):
    return (i % 2) == 0

def is_odd(i):
    return (i % 2) != 0

def get_evens_at_back(l):
    odds = list(filter(is_odd, l))
    evens = list(filter(is_even, l))

    return sorted(odds) + sorted(evens)
```